# How to upgrade to a 2.6.39 kernel?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

Kernel ppa is empty.

https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa

Is available 2.6.39.2 kernel for natty? How to upgrade?

Comment: That's weird, all packages from `ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa` vanished somehow. A few days ago, it did indeed include some kernels including the 2.6.39 one.

Answer (score 2):

The [2.6.39.2 kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.39.2-oneiric/) is named "oneiric" - but according to [this ubuntu mailing list entry](http://old.nabble.com/Mainline-Build-v2.6.39.2-td31920433.html), this kernel is the generic kernel without any specific modifications for ubuntu & oneiric.

You will need to install the kernel yourself:

Browse to the following location on Launchpad - link is below.

If you have a 64bit system download the two amd64.deb files.

If you have a 32bit system download the two i386.deb files.

In addition download the "_all.deb" file.

then install the downloaded debs

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Then update your grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.39.2-oneiric/

Comment: Is that a typo?  Should that be 'dpkg'?

Comment: very observant - thanks.  Don't forget, this is a contributor site - you are most welcome to edit any question and answer where you can improve them.

Comment: Sure. But I don't consider myself enough of a linux expert to be sure enough that was really a typo, which is why I left that for you to decide :)  BTW thanks for this answer. I did get this kernel installed on my Linux Mint 11 installation and am hoping it stops the darn freezing issue that's been haunting me.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can Try:

---

### [KernelCheck.](http://kcheck.sourceforge.net/)

---

KernelCheck is a graphical user interface program designed to make the kernel-compiling process as easy as the click of a button. A kernel is the base of any operating system – in our case, the Linux operating system. KernelCheck will fetch the latest information from http://www.kernel.org, which hosts the source packages for the Linux kernel, and ask the user which one they would like to compile into a .deb package (with the option of installing the kernel after the compilation).

This automated process is a fork of AutoKernel by Robert Wolterman (xtacocorex), Timothy Janssen (mentok), and Kristof Verbeken (PingunZ). KernelCheck is currently licensed under the GNU Public License version 3.

Current Features:

- Ability to download, compile and
  install latest kernel automatically
- Ability to compare latest kernel
  information with your current running
  kernel
- GUI designed with Glade
  provides easy accessibility for any
  user Supported Platforms

At the moment, KernelCheck is only supported on Debian-Based platforms. Some of these include Debian, Ubuntu (or any derivatives), Mint, etc. RPM and Slackware based are planned to be supported in the future.

[Source.](http://kcheck.sourceforge.net/about.html)

[image]

Comment: I always use this to update the kernel, it's easy & simple, and it doesn't take too much time to compile the kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me: http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/5408/kernelcheck.png
Any ideas?

Comment: Id doesn't work for me too :(

Comment: Which version did you download?, according to their blog, that's because the files were removed from the server kernelcheck , checks.

Comment: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/35212126/kernelcheck_1.2.5-3_all.deb use this deb

Answer (score 0):

Compiling a kernel under Ubuntu (even with the command line) is quite easy:

Just install the kernel-package package (:D):

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install kernel-package
```

and then download the kernel sources from http://kernel.org (under the "Latest Stable Kernel" heading) to a working directory, such as `~/kernels`. Then to actually compile the kernel, run:

```
cd ~/kernels
```

to change to your working directory. For the next two steps, it's a good idea to open your file manager, so you can see the names of the files and folders easily. Now, you need to extract the archive you downloaded. You can either run the command below or right click the file and click "Extract."

```
tar jxvf name-of-file.tar.bz2
```

Now, change to the directory that was created when you extracted the source archive.

```
cd name-of-folder
```

Next, you need to copy the kernel configuration. 99% of the time, Ubuntu's default configuration will work just fine.

```
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
```

Finally, to compile the kernel, just run: [Note: CONCURRENCY_LEVEL should be set to the number of processor cores + 1. It will speed up the compile time a lot]

```
CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=3 fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd kernel_image kernel_headers
```

In your `~/kernels` folder, you will find two shiny new DEB's waiting to be installed :D

Comment: The newer versions of make-kpkg have a --jobs switch, so you don't need to set CONCURRENCY_LEVEL anymore. Also, to fill in some of the holes in the .config it's best to run one of the config methods before running make-kpkg. Something like: `make oldconfig` Or if you want to go in depth and look at some of the new options: `make menuconfig`