# Wireless stops working soon after computer start when using WPA2 encryption

Tags: 14.04, wireless, 15.04, lenovo, wpa2

I'm having a weird problem with my computer where my wifi stops working some time after my computer starts up. The only way to get it working again is to restart my computer. I know the problem is not with any of the hardware because it works perfectly fine with the Windows 10 I dual boot with.

**System info**

```
Manufacturer: Lenovo
Model: G50-70
OS: 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Kernel: 3.16.0-46-generic
```

**This problem also occurs in:**

```
OS: 64-bit Ubuntu 15.04
Kernel: 3.18.21-031821-generic
```

**Network controller info:**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 28:d2:44:e1:6f:15
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.040.00-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0504000-c0504fff memory:c0500000-c0503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 38:b1:db:7c:18:bd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.18.21-031821-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.66 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0400000-c0403fff
```

Please post any comments if you need additional info.

**Update:**

Switching the router over to WEP encryption seems to fix the problem. However, WEP is insecure so it would be appreciated if a different fix was found.

**Update:**

This problem is also in Ubuntu 15.10. However, you can simply disconnect and then reconnect in order to solve the problem temporarily. After 2 minutes to 2 hours, the problem happens again.

**Similar Questions:**

[Internet Randomly Stops Working, But Starts Working Again Upon Reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667514/internet-randomly-stops-working-but-starts-working-again-upon-reboot?lq=1)
[Wireless keeps cutting out every several minutes on a Realtek RTL8187SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52238/wireless-keeps-cutting-out-every-several-minutes-on-a-realtek-rtl8187se?rq=1)

Comment: What is the encryption in your router? TKIP or AES?

Comment: @Pilot6 How do I find out which one?

Comment: You can look in your router web interface. TKIP may not be supported.

Comment: Or run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`, find your SSID and see `Group Cipher :`

Comment: Router web interface: `WPA or WPA2 Personal` is a specific as it gets. 
Terminal command: `wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.`

Comment: Can you set it to WPA2 only, or it can be called "AES" or "CCMP"?

Comment: Ah, I found it. It uses both TKIP and AES security. Yes, I can set it to WPA2 only. I can also choose for it to only use TKIP or only use AES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and reboot:

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

This will disable some of the power management of the card and usually helps.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. http://askubuntu.com/tour That will help the searchers.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I thought I had already done it.

Comment: This no longer works in Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by installing another driver. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Comment: @TheNumberOne Sry, fixed it.

Comment: This fails to fix the problem :(

Comment: It should fix it. Did it install OK?

Comment: It did install OK. The wireless worked for only about 3 minutes after the last startup.

Comment: Your ppa repository no longer works in Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @TheNumberOne It never worked for 15.10. Is it needed for kernel 4.2?

Comment: @TheNumberOne You said that this solution had not worked for you, so why worry about the ppa?

Comment: The other fix no longer works in Ubuntu 15.10. I was wondering if this would fix the problem in 15.10.